How can I animate a png icon and add it to video?
I want to use blender as video editor to add animated objects, text and transitions to video from screen.
I understand how to make an animation separately, in the Viewport window. But I don't understand how to make the picture animation on the video itself. I want it to appear on the video preview and then make a keyframe to move or rotate it, but on video coordinates.
Is it possible?
Example. I made a video from screen. Now I downloaded a red arrow and I want it to move from one point on the video to another smoothly.

Hello could you please tell a bit more about your animation? It's a bit vague for the moment. There are 3 ways to do motion design: 3d view, Compositor and Video Sequencer, the choice will depends on your animation and also what you feel comfortable with

Hello, as I am editing a video, I would like to animate simple object from Video Sequencer, to see them on preview (otherwise I can't see where they'll be positioned on video).

So Shift A to import the image into the Video Sequencer, open the N panel > Strip > Transform and keyframe the Position and Rotation values?

It is possible only by moving second by second and changing position and rotation manually in settings, then saving this as keypoint?

ShiftA to import the image into the Video Sequencer, open the N panel > Strip > Transform and keyframe the Position and Rotation values to move the image, note that you can manipulate the image in the Video Sequencer > Preview window:

To create a keyframe, put your blue cursor at the frame you want, set the transform value you want, put your mouse over the value and press i, then move your blue cursor further on the timeline, change the value and keyframe again. There will be an automatic interpolation between the 2 keyframes.

seem to work, I move, I click Animate near position and rotation. Like that? What mean keys with orange strip between them and what mean separate keys?

the orange line means that their is no difference betwen the 2 keyframes, the object wont't move or rotate. I've edited my answer to explain how keyframes work;
